# How to fix session not starting after unsetting a variable

Tags: php, session, indexing

Please I have been trying to fix this but not working out right for me. I have a session started but after logging out using `unset($_SESSION['variable']`, I am unable to login back as the session is not setting.

> Please help me out. Note: I am unable to login after unsetting the variable.

```
//this is login.php
<?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();
    $msg = "";
    if (isset($_POST['login'])){
        include "dbconnect.php";
        if($_SESSION['emaill'] !== NULL){
            $emaill= $_SESSION['emaill'];
            $passWord = $_POST['passWord'];
            if (empty($emaill && $passWord) == false){
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `sono` WHERE `eMail`='$emaill' && `passWord`='$passWord'";
                $check = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($dbconnect));
                $result = mysqli_num_rows($check);
                if ($result > 0){
                    $emaill= $_SESSION['emaill'];
                    header ('location: home.php');
                    exit();
                } else
                    $msg = "<p style='color: red; padding-left: 10px'>Invalid password or email address</p>";
            } else
                $msg = "<p style='color: red; padding-left: 10px'>Please enter your email and password to login</p>";
        } else
            $msg = "<p style='color: red; padding-left: 10px'>My scripts not working yet</p>";
    }
?>

// this is for logout
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['emaill'])){
        unset($_SESSION['emaill']);
        header('location: login.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: In logout, you destroy `$_SESSION['emaill']` but when you attempt to login again, you dont check for the existance of `email` in line 8 ` if($_SESSION['emaill'] !== NULL){` before attempting to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before using $_SESSION['emaill'], check it with isset() like :

```
if( isset($_SESSION['emaill']) && $_SESSION['emaill'] !== NULL){
----
---
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahjith. i have tested the email, it's no more existing. It's not giving me undefined index again but the login query is not working. Showing the last error above I asigned in the script.  $msg = "<p>My scripts not working yet</p>";

Comment: echo your sql and try to run it in mysql directly and check what error it showing

Comment: After echoing sql,  It's showing Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\buth_net\nursingSchool\login.php on line 22 and when I run it from mysql, it returning emptry result. I think the major now is that, session is not starting after logging out.

Answer (score 0):

Add `isset` check here

```
if(isset($_SESSION['emaill']) && $_SESSION['emaill'] !== NULL){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the empty function before SESSION to check the value exists or not . As the variable is being unset or destroyed at the time of logout it is unable to recognize the SESSION at the time of login . You can try checking like this below :-

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['emaill']))
{

// Your code here 

}
```